# Angular: Routing to a different page dependent on a API return

Tags: angular, typescript

What I want to do is go to a different page (more accurately Skip a page) dependent on what is returned from a API endpoint:

The API currently returns the following:

```
int: id
name: string
```

I have been able to call this and can check in the console and see its returning the right int and name

However, in my TS file I have the following check:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.appService.showLoader(true);
    this.coachService.GetCategories().subscribe(res =>
     {
      this.appService.showLoader(false);
      if (res && res.length === 0){
          this.appService.openSnackBar('You do not have access to this Service');
          this.disabled = true;
          } else if (res && res.length === 1) {
            if( res[0].name === 'Mindset'){
                this.disabled = false;
                localStorage.setItem(localKeys.SELECTED_SESSION_TYPE, SupportAreaCategory.Mindset.toString());
                this.coachService.storeMatchMakerPayload(SupportAreaCategory.Mindset, 'CategoryId');
                this.router.navigate([`${appRoutesNames.COACH_INTERACTION}/${coachInteractionRouteNames.MATCH_MAKING}/${coachMatchMakingRouteNames.MINDSET}`]);
             }
            if(res[1].name === 'Growth'){
                this.disabled = false;
                localStorage.setItem(localKeys.SELECTED_SESSION_TYPE, SupportAreaCategory.Growth.toString());
                this.coachService.storeMatchMakerPayload(SupportAreaCategory.Growth, 'CategoryId');
                this.router.navigate([`${appRoutesNames.COACH_INTERACTION}/${coachInteractionRouteNames.MATCH_MAKING}/${coachMatchMakingRouteNames.GROWTH}`]);
            }
        }
      }, () => {}
      );
  }
```

This is not going to the right page however and in fact appears to be doing nothing, I do have a couple of restrictions:

I have to find the Name from the API to return and compare that (for example match 'Growth' with 'Growth')

Routes:

```
export const COACH_MATCH_MAKING_ROUTES = [
  {path: '', component:CoachMatchmakingComponent},
  { path: coachMatchMakingRouteNames.COACH_SESSION, component: CoachSessionTypeComponent },
  { path: coachMatchMakingRouteNames.GROWTH, component: GrowthComponent },
  { path: coachMatchMakingRouteNames.MINDSET, component: MindsetComponent },
  { path: coachMatchMakingRouteNames.FUNCTIONAL_BACKGROUND, component: FunctionalBackgroundComponent },
  { path: coachMatchMakingRouteNames.INDUSTRY_EXPERTISE, component: IndustryExpertiseComponent },
  { path: coachMatchMakingRouteNames.COACH_MATCHER, component:CoachMatcherComponent },
  { path: coachMatchMakingRouteNames.COACH_DETAILS, component:CoachDetailsComponent },
  { path: coachMatchMakingRouteNames.COACH_MATCHED_ANIMATION, component:CoachMatchedAnimationComponent },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

@SCOCB, I believe you are using `wrongly` the router here and how to navigate you should either do :

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(`/${appRoutesNames.COACH_INTERACTION}/${coachInteractionRouteNames.MATCH_MAKING}/${coachMatchMakingRouteNames.GROWTH}`)
```

Or do

```
this.router.navigate([appRoutesNames.COACH_INTERACTION, coachInteractionRouteNames.MATCH_MAKING, coachMatchMakingRouteNames.GROWTH])
```

You can check the router documentation https://angular.io/api/router

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Thanks, I used the 2nd option and I get the same result, it continues to open the Create Session Page instead (it never bypasses this page)

Comment: Could you share, your routes config, the result or how the route looks like when built ?

Comment: Added to main post

Comment: Could you add all the routes involved and how they are defined ? Your app routes. COACH_MATCH_MAKING_ROUTES is just the last part of the routes, still need COACH_INTERACTION & MATCH_MAKING routes

Comment: I am looking on how you implemented the loadChildren routes